# Test Login Page having Base Authentication using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am testing a web application(UI) using Selenium C# and deployed with azure CI CD pipeline to a remote server. As the UI application runs over a private network, when it redirects to the login page in the remote machine, the test fails because in the local machine test, the UI will take credentials (windows credentials auto-login), but in the remote server it is waiting for credentials.

I have gone through multiple solutions like passing username and password over the URL which also failed.
Using a third-party AutoIT tool is restricted in my project. Is there any solution for this?

Should we able to add any pipeline task to add the credentials once the release CD pipeline starts deploying?

Anybody, please help!!!!

I am using azure DevOps ci/cd pipeline
Selenium-Cucumber framework for testing using C#

[image]

Comment: look at AUTOIT. That is a windows object and selenium will not be able to interact with it.

Comment: I cant use AUTOIT as its a third party application.It has been restricted from my client side

Comment: Is there Any powershell script to add chrome user in release pipeline?

Comment: If you have API for  login  you can try add code for login via API, save cookie and then pass that cookie to selenium web driver